# Write value to CSV Column with RUBY

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv

I have columns with headers as such:

`First,Last,ID,Type`

The first row of data looks like this:

`Jon,Smith,123,,`

There is no value under the fourth column `Type`.

I have a script that parses each column into an array and does different actions based on the first three criteria, `First,Last,ID`.

I need to write to the CSV file. The logic would look like this:

`If First == Jon, Last == Smith, and ID == 123, write "Success" to Type`

I have the following script:

```
   CSV.open("Content_File.csv", "wb") do |csv|
     csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
     csv << ["another", "row"]
```

but all it does is write content to a CSV file row by row. I need to write to a specific row and a specific column.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is you cannot (that is, you still need to iterate through the whole file and write out another one). For The longer version, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430903/replacing-text-in-one-csv-column-using-fastercsv).

Comment: Gotcha. I suppose I could pull all the existing CSV values and just overwrite the file, passing in my new value alongside all the old values. I'll probably just write a new CSV file and do a VLOOKUP though. Thanks for the guidance.