# How would you replace the headers in a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm brand new to ruby, and fairly new to programming.

How would you change the headers of a csv file?

```
foo, bar, foobar
1,   2,   3,
4,   5,   6,
7,   8,   9,
```

Change to:

```
herp, derp, herpaderp
1,    2,    3,
4,    5,    6,
7,    8,    9,
```

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430903/replacing-text-in-one-csv-column-using-fastercsv), however it doesn't really apply since I'm using the built in 'csv' library instead of the older 'fastcsv' library. (using ruby 2.0.0 on Mac OSX)

What I've tried.

```
require 'csv'
@filename = ARGV[0]
new_headers = ["herp", "derp", "herpaderp"]

origional_csv = CSV.read(@filename, {headers: true, return_headers: true })
headers = CSV.open(@filename, 'r', :headers => true).read.headers
puts headers

#Change headers to new_headers ?
```

Calling test.rb from the command line with foo.csv file

```
$ ruby test.rb foo.csv
foo, bar, foobar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to do this with the CSV library. Just change the first line of the file, output the rest the same:

```
lines = File.readlines(@filename)
lines.shift
lines.unshift(["herp", "derp", "herpaderp"].join(',') + "\n")
puts lines.join('')
```

Comment: I think, update in the same file is not possible partially. Am I right? need to copy data from one file, after processing data, sent those data to a new file..

Comment: Update in place isn't possible unless the header text is *exactly* the same length. It's usually best to re-write to a different file anyway in case you screw something up.