# How to find and replace element in CSV

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv

How do I find and replace a pattern such as the quotes surrounding `"West"` in the below example of a CSV file?

```
"LastName","FirstName","","","890","","6G","","S "West" AVENUE","","CITY","ZIP"
```

Comment: What is the output of this: `CSV.foreach('your_file.csv') do |row|
  p row
end`  You can post just the first few lines.

Comment: We need to know what you've tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing text in one CSV column using FasterCSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430903/replacing-text-in-one-csv-column-using-fastercsv)

Comment: I tried using  csv.grep(/("[a-zA-Z]")/) to identify earlier examples but that only worked for one character in between.

Comment: the output won't run because of an error saying misplaced quote on line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use [the CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to read this because it's a malformed CSV string. Sometimes that happens because whoever generated it didn't know what they were doing:

```
require 'csv'
foo = '"LastName","FirstName","","","890","","6G","","S "West" AVENUE","","CITY","ZIP"'
arr_of_arrs = CSV.parse(foo)
```

Which then results in an exception:

```
Missing or stray quote in line 1 (CSV::MalformedCSVError)
```

Instead, to deal with this, you have to fix up the data, then parse. Here's a starting point:

```
/(?<=\s)("[^"]+")(?=\s)/
```

http://rubular.com/r/sWEkx07Zyo

The pattern is looking for something between quotes, wrapped with leading and trailing spaces. The spaces are not captured.

Here's some code that'd work for this particular example:

```
foo = '"LastName","FirstName","","","890","","6G","","S "West" AVENUE","","CITY","ZIP"'

REGEX = /(?<=\s)("[^"]+")(?=\s)/

word = foo[REGEX]
foo[REGEX] = word[1..-2]
puts foo
# >> "LastName","FirstName","","","890","","6G","","S West AVENUE","","CITY","ZIP"
```

At this point CSV could be used:

```
require 'csv'
arr_of_arrs = CSV.parse(foo)
# => [["LastName",
#      "FirstName",
#      "",
#      "",
#      "890",
#      "",
#      "6G",
#      "",
#      "S West AVENUE",
#      "",
#      "CITY",
#      "ZIP"]]
```

This stuff might be confusing:

```
word = foo[REGEX]
foo[REGEX] = word[1..-2]
```

[`foo\[...\]` is part of the String class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), and is a nice and convenient way to find and replace characters in a string.

---

It's possible to get the CSV parser to be happy with the embedded quotes though, so if throwing them away is too heavy handed, you can do something like:

```
word = foo[REGEX]
foo[REGEX] = '"%s"' % word

require 'csv'
arr_of_arrs = CSV.parse(foo)
# => [["LastName",
#      "FirstName",
#      "",
#      "",
#      "890",
#      "",
#      "6G",
#      "",
#      "S \"West\" AVENUE",
#      "",
#      "CITY",
#      "ZIP"]]
```

Which simply plays by the CSV spec's rules and uses doubled double-quotes around the string.

Comment: Good answer. I especially liked your second sentence. In fact, that is the root of so many problems, not just in coding, but in life generally.

Comment: LOL. Thanks. Just calling it as I see it. And I've seen it too many times.